# Using key-value pair RDD to build a kdtree in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to build kd-trees from points in a pair RDD called "RDDofPoints" with type RDD[BoundingBox[Double],(Double,Double)]. All the points are assigned to a particular bounding box and my goal is to build a kd-tree for each of the Bounding Boxes.

I am trying to use reduceByKey for this purpose. However, I am stuck at how to call the buildtree function in this case.

The function declaration of buildtree is:

```
def buildtree(points: RDD[(Double, Double)], depth: Int = 0): Option[KdNodeforRDD]
```

And, I am trying to call it as:

```
val treefromPairRDD = RDDofPoints.reduceByKey((k,v) => buildtree(v))
```

This does not work obviously. I am fairly new to Scala and Spark, please suggest what could be the appropriate way to go about in this situation. I am not sure about using reduceByKey, if some other pair RDD function can be applied here, which one would it be?

Thank you.